# Jekyll: is it possible to use Liquid tags in a CSS file? ( Re: Content Security Policy compliance)

Tags: jekyll, liquid, content-security-policy

In a Jekyll page, I have the following inline style:

> `<div class="myClass" style="background-image: url({% if`
> `latest_post.image contains "://" %}{{ latest_post.image }}{% else %}`
> `{{site.baseurl}}/{{ latest_post.image}}{% endif %});`
> `height:320px;"></div>`

For preventing any CSP violation/error, in the header, I set the CSP as follows:

> style-src 'self' 'unsafe-hashes' 'sha256-GlN6IkeSF4fF9C8zesLvRQRzAe2/ztqCm4T50cOnYvY='

But I am still getting the following warning in a few browsers such as Google Chrome, and Microsoft Edge:

> CSS inline styles should not be used, move styles to an external CSS file

Therefore, I tried to move the inline style to an external CSS file as follows:

1. Added an empty YAML block to the beginning of the CSS file
2. Added the following CSS style containing the Liquid tags:

> `.myClass { background-image: url({% if latest_post.image contains "://" %}{{ latest_post.image }}{% else %} {{site.baseurl}}/{{`
> `latest_post.image}}{% endif %}); height:320px; }`

However, the Liquid tags added to the CSS file are not processed. In fact, in the resulting HTML page, I don't see the background-image is not shown on the page accordingly.

I would expect to see the background image accordingly.

Is it possible to properly move that inline style, and those Liquid tags, to an external CSS file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [entry SASS file](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/assets/) can contain Liquid templating. SASS partials cannot. Here's an example file: https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-sass-converter/blob/master/docs/assets/css/main.scss

You could either create a SASS variable containing that value, or use it directly in the main SASS/SCSS file (the one with the triple dashes at the top - likely called `main.scss`):

```
---
---

{% assign latest_post = site.posts[0] %}

.myClass {
  background-image: url({% if latest_post.image contains "://" %}{{ latest_post.image }}{% else %}{{ site.baseurl }}/{{ latest_post.image }}{% endif %});
  height: 320px;
}
```

Comment: That is the best answer I got so far, and it provides the perfect example. However, the file is called main.css. There isn't any SCSS file in the project solution at the moment.

Comment: That's true I did assume SASS. I believe during preprocessing Jekyll doesn't mind what type or extension a file has, just that it starts with `---`.